# Javascript - formation button- method post

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, methods

I am not expert of javascript.
I'm working on a project for implementing a javascript web interface like in the first picture.[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UerIc.png)

This is a form. When I select an option in the first and a second select I get the second line displayed in the second picture.[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyfac.png)

On the second line you can see that I implemented an other button, which execute a php script. I would like that, when I execute it with the method post, the result would appear on the side frame (where is written TEST). So, this means that I have a form action associated to the button on the first line and another button on the second line. I would like that, when I click on the first button (on first line) a php script with method post would open in a new window. On the other hand, if I click the button on the second line, I would like to execute another php script with the method post and that its results appears on the side frame.
To implement this I used a formaction for the second button. However I cannot pass the variables coming from the selects.
Could anyone give me some ints to fix this issue?

I write here the code I used.
I didn't post the two scripts php as they are really trivial.

```js
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../calendar/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../calendar/datepicker.js"></script>      
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../calendar/datepicker.css">  
</head>
<body>
   
      
<script>
 var arrayA = ["Chap1"];

 var arrayB = ["Chap1"];

 var myForm = document.createElement("FORM");
 myForm.setAttribute("method","post");
 myForm.setAttribute("id","myForm");
 myForm.target ="";
 document.body.appendChild(myForm);
 
 var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
 button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
 button.setAttribute("formaction","test.php.php");
 button.setAttribute("formtarget","_blank");
 //----------- Select a matter-------------------------------------
 var arrayMatter = ["Choose a matter","Choice A","Choice B"];
 mySelect("matterSelect", arrayMatter, myForm);
 
 //------------ Select an operation---------------------------------
 var arrayOperations = ["Choose an operation",
                        "Execute it"];
   
 mySelect("operationSelect", arrayOperations, myForm);

 myForm.appendChild(button);
 
 document.getElementById("matterSelect").addEventListener("click", function(){dropDownReset()});

 document.getElementById("operationSelect").addEventListener("click", function(){dropDownOperations()}); 

 //_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 //----------------- FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 
 //------------ Function to create a Select ------------------------------
 function mySelect(id, options, parent){
  var myselect = document.createElement("SELECT");
     myselect.setAttribute("id", id);
     parent.appendChild(myselect);
     
  for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
   
      var matterOption = document.createElement("option");
      matterOption.setAttribute("value", options[i]);
      var matterNode = document.createTextNode(options[i]);
      matterOption.appendChild(matterNode);
      myselect.appendChild(matterOption);
  }
 }

 //------------ Function to create a checkbox with text ------------------------------
    function myCheckBox(id, text){

  var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
        
     var mycheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
     mycheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
     mycheckbox.setAttribute("id", id);
     mycheckbox.setAttribute("name", id); 

  cell1.appendChild(mycheckbox);
  document.getElementById("chapterTable").appendChild(cell1);    
     
     var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
     var checkboxNode = document.createTextNode(text);
     cell2.appendChild(checkboxNode);
  document.getElementById("chapterTable").appendChild(cell2);
     
  var arrayMinDfLevel = ["Choose min difficulty level","1","2","3","4","5"];
  var arrayMaxDfLevel = ["Choose max difficulty level","1","2","3","4","5"];

  var cell3 = document.createElement("TD");
  mySelect("selectMinDfLevel"+id,arrayMinDfLevel,cell3);
  document.getElementById("chapterTable").appendChild(cell3);
  document.getElementById("selectMinDfLevel"+id).disabled = true; 
  
  var cell4 = document.createElement("TD");
  mySelect("selectMaxDfLevel"+id,arrayMaxDfLevel,cell4);
  document.getElementById("chapterTable").appendChild(cell4);
  document.getElementById("selectMaxDfLevel"+id).disabled = true;

  var butt = document.createElement("Input");
  butt.setAttribute("id","butt"+id);
  butt.setAttribute("type","submit");
  butt.setAttribute("formtarget","SideFrame");

  butt.setAttribute("method","post");
   
  butt.setAttribute("formaction","SideFrame.php");
  

  var textButt = document.createTextNode("Get Exercises list");
  butt.appendChild(textButt);
  document.getElementById("chapterTable").appendChild(butt);
  document.getElementById("butt"+id).disabled = true;

  
  mycheckbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
      if(this.checked) {
       document.getElementById("selectMinDfLevel"+id).disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("selectMaxDfLevel"+id).disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("butt"+id).disabled = false; 
      } else {
       document.getElementById("selectMinDfLevel"+id).disabled = true;
       document.getElementById("selectMaxDfLevel"+id).disabled = true; 
       document.getElementById("butt"+id).disabled = true;
      }
  });
 }
       
 //------------ Function to create a submit ------------------------------
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
     }

 //------------ Function to reset chapters ------------------------------
     function dropDownReset() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").removeChild(document.getElementById("divTest"));
     }

     function displayListOptions(matter, subject, diff_level_min, diff_level_max){
         var urlget = "var1='"+var1+"'&diff_level_min="+diff_level_min+"&diff_level_max="+diff_level_max;
         windows.location.href =  "./SideFrame.php?"+urlget;    
     }

     function dropDownOperations(){
        var arrayS = [];
        if(document.getElementById("matterSelect").options[document.getElementById("matterSelect").selectedIndex].value == "Choice A"){
    arrayS = arrayA;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("matterSelect").options[document.getElementById("matterSelect").selectedIndex].value == "Choice B"){
          arrayS = arrayB;
        }
         
     var opSelect = document.getElementById("operationSelect");
      
     if(opSelect.options[opSelect.selectedIndex].value == "Créer une séquence d'entrainement random"){
           
     }
     else if(opSelect.options[opSelect.selectedIndex].value == "Execute it"){
         
       var divTest = document.createElement("div");
      divTest.setAttribute("id","divTest");
      document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(divTest);

       var chapterTable1 = document.createElement("TABLE");
      chapterTable1.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
      divTest.appendChild(chapterTable1);

      var row1 = document.createElement("TR");
      row1.setAttribute("id", "myRow");
      chapterTable1.appendChild(row1); 
      
      var chapterTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
      chapterTable.setAttribute("id", "chapterTable");
      divTest.appendChild(chapterTable);
      
      for(k = 0; k < 1; k++){
          var row = document.createElement("TR");
          row.setAttribute("id", "myRow"+k);
          chapterTable.appendChild(row);
       myCheckBox("chapter"+k,arrayS[k]);
      }
     }
     }
       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<frameset cols="70%,30%">
 <frame id ="GeneralPanel" name="GeneralPanel" heigth = 1000 width = 700 src="GeneralPanel_v002.php">
 <frame id = "SideFrame" name="SideFrame" src="SideFrame.php">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "However I cannot pass the variables coming from the selects". Pass which variables and pass them where?

Also why such a long story. Try to simplify your example and your question. It's very hard for the reader to figure out what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi, 
first of all, thanks for your answer. I try to explain better my problem.
I have a form with a double button. The first button call a new window and execute a php script. The second button should execute a query to a mySQL DB based on values selected between different options. My problem is that, when I choose those values, they are not passed by post method to the php script.

Comment: I would like to precise that, the second button should be executed with a form target  corresponding to the right side frame of the general frame.